# LAST DIGIT OF BILLION DIGIT NUMBER

Tags: javascript, exponent

how would you find the last digit of something like this mathematically? i am pretty sure i can translate the math into code, but i don't know how to do the math

eqn:

```
2^(3^(4^(5^(6^(7^(8^(9^10)))))))
```

Comment: Step 1 is to find a JavaScript "bignum" library that can do the job. Step 2 is to use it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about math, not programming. math.stackexchange.com would be a more appropriate site.

Comment: sorry ive been on there but i thought since this was code related, it was ok to post this here

Comment: oh im on this website called code wars. great site. only allows vanilla js

Comment: @tadman step 3: wait several (hundred?) years for the result to appear

Comment: @Barmar There should be no javascript solution in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: In binary system it would be 0

Comment: @choz The question is about the math, not how to write it in JS.

Comment: @Barmar If I get this correctly, he wants to convert the math equation to javascript solution. If this is true, I've seen such questions on SO forum..

Comment: @choz "I'm pretty sure I can translate the math into code, but I don't know how to do the math". Anyway, look at the answer, there's no code required to solve it.

Comment: @Barmar I see, let's wait for OP's clarification what he exactly wants.. I agree that this is currently a math problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modular arithmetic problem. You're looking to compute (huge number) base 10. It can be done pretty quickly on paper.

2<sup>x</sup> mod 10 = 2<sup>(x mod 4)</sup> mod 10, since 2<sup>5</sup> mod 10 = 2<sup>1</sup> mod 10. Thus we are only interested in 2<sup>(big number.... mod 4)</sup>.

3<sup>x</sup> mod 4 = 3<sup>(x mod 2)</sup> mod 4, since 3<sup>3</sup> mod 4 = 3<sup>1</sup> mod 4. Thus we are only interested in 2<sup>3<sup>(big number... mod 2)</sup></sup>.

4<sup>x</sup> mod 2 = 0

Working backwards,

3<sup>0</sup> = 1

2<sup>1</sup> = 2

Therefore my answer is 2.

Comment: the mod is mosulo right?